# Loop doesnt wait for animation to be finished before iterating to next animation

Tags: java, javafx

After a player moves a stone (Candycrush-like game), in the logic i gather information about if the player move result in a *Structure*, which then needs to be *exploded*. Ofcourse once a Structure gets exploded by removing the structure elements and dropping the stones above, new Structures can appear that also needs to be exploded sequentially.

For that i have an AnimationData class that has a List of ExplosionData, which has the size of the found structures, caused by the initial player move.

My code works fine for just ONE explosion but messes up if there are multiple explosions. The problem is that the loop doesn't wait until the explosion animation is done before it continues the iteration.

Clarification : method updateGui, loop inside switchAnimation.setOnFinished

Visually :
[Clips of a single Explosion and multiple Explosion that i recorded](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gCWqOexJZtcmAe1PBInoVQ5ELYQhy3PE)

```
public void updateGui(AnimationData aData) {
    final int rowHeight = (int) (boardGPane.getHeight() / boardGPane.getRowConstraints().size());
    Coords switchSourceCoords = aData.getSwitchSourceCoords();
    Coords switchTargetCoords = aData.getSwitchTargetCoords();

    // Apply player move
    ParallelTransition switchAnimation = switchStones(switchSourceCoords, switchTargetCoords);
    switchAnimation.play();
    // Revert switch, if the move was invalid
    if (aData.geteData().isEmpty()) {
        switchAnimation.setOnFinished(event -> {
            ParallelTransition switchBackAnimation = switchStones(switchSourceCoords, switchTargetCoords);
            switchBackAnimation.play();
        });
    } else {
        switchAnimation.setOnFinished(event -> {
            // Animate explosions for every found Structure
            for (ExplosionData eData : aData.geteData()) {
                SequentialTransition explosionAnimation = new SequentialTransition();
                // Coordinates of where the bonusStone appears
                Coords bonusSource = eData.getBonusSourceCoords();
                // Coordinates of where the bonusStone need to be repositioned
                Coords bonusTarget = eData.getBonusTargetCoords();

                // Remove all Structure elements and make Stones above drop to their target
                // positions. Also translate them back to the same position for the animation
                removeStructureAndReplaceIvs(eData, bonusTarget, bonusSource, rowHeight);
                // This shall only proceed if the animation involves handeling a bonusStone
                if (bonusSource != null && bonusTarget != null) {
                    int rowsToMove = bonusTarget.getRow() - bonusSource.getRow();
                    ImageView bonusIv = (ImageView) JavaFXGUI.getNodeFromGridPane(boardGPane, bonusTarget.getCol(), bonusTarget.getRow());
                    // BonusStone shall fade in at the source Position
                    explosionAnimation = bonusStoneFadeIn(explosionAnimation, rowsToMove, bonusIv, rowHeight);
                    // Translate to targetPosition, if sourcePosition is not equal to targetPosition
                    explosionAnimation = bonusStoneMoveToTargetCoords(explosionAnimation, rowsToMove, bonusIv, rowHeight);
                }
                // Make the Stone ImageViews translate from their origin position to their new target positions
                explosionAnimation = dropAndFillUpEmptySpace(explosionAnimation, eData, bonusTarget, bonusSource, rowHeight);
                explosionAnimation.play();
            }
        });
    }
}


private void removeStructureAndReplaceIvs(ExplosionData eData,
                                          Coords bonusTargetCoords,
                                          Coords bonusSourceCoords,
                                          final int rowHeight) {
    // Removing the Structure and all stones above by deleting the ImageViews col by col
    for (DropInfo info : eData.getExplosionInfo()) {
        // Coordinates of the Structure element that is going to be removed in this col
        int col = info.getCoords().getCol();
        int row = info.getCoords().getRow();
        // If a bonusStone will apear, the heightOffset gets reduced by one
        int offset = getAppropiateOffset(bonusTargetCoords, info, col);

        // Remove the Structure and all ImageViews above
        removeImageViewsFromCells(col, row, row + 1);

        List<String> stoneToken = info.getFallingStoneToken();
        for (int r = row, i = 0; r >= 0; --r, ++i) {
            // Fill up removed Cells with new ImageViews values
            ImageView newIv = new ImageView(new Image(preImagePath + stoneToken.get(i) + ".png"));
            // Place each iv to their target Coords
            addImageViewToPane(newIv, col, r);
            // Translate all non-bonusStones to the position they were placed before
            if (ignoreBonusTargetCoordinates(bonusTargetCoords, bonusSourceCoords, r, col)) {
                newIv.setTranslateY(-rowHeight * offset);
            }
        }
    }
}

// If the removed Structure results to generate a bonusStone, make it fade in at source position
private SequentialTransition bonusStoneFadeIn(SequentialTransition explosionAnimation,
                                        int sourceToTargetDiff,
                                        ImageView bonusIv,
                                        final int rowHeight) {
    FadeTransition bonusFadeIn = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(1), bonusIv);
    bonusFadeIn.setFromValue(0f);
    bonusFadeIn.setToValue(1f);
    // If the target Position is not the same, place it to target and translate to source position
    if (sourceToTargetDiff > 0) {
        bonusIv.setTranslateY(-rowHeight * sourceToTargetDiff);
    }

    explosionAnimation.getChildren().add(bonusFadeIn);
    return explosionAnimation;
}

// If the bonusStone must be moved from source Coordinates to target Coordinates
private SequentialTransition bonusStoneMoveToTargetCoords(SequentialTransition explosionAnimation,
                                                          int sourceToTargetDiff,
                                                          ImageView bonusIv,
                                                          final int rowHeight) {
    // Difference in row from bonusSourceCoordinates to bonusTargetCoordinates
    if (sourceToTargetDiff > 0) {
        TranslateTransition moveToTargetCoords = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(1), bonusIv);
        moveToTargetCoords.fromYProperty().set(-rowHeight * sourceToTargetDiff);
        moveToTargetCoords.toYProperty().set(0);
        explosionAnimation.getChildren().add(moveToTargetCoords);
    }
    return explosionAnimation;
}

private SequentialTransition dropAndFillUpEmptySpace(SequentialTransition explosionAnimation,
                                                     ExplosionData eData,
                                                     Coords bonusTargetCoords,
                                                     Coords bonusSourceCoords,
                                                     final int rowHeight) {
    ParallelTransition animateDrop = new ParallelTransition();
    for (int i = 0; i < eData.getExplosionInfo().size(); i++) {
        // List of all stoneToken to create respective ImageViews for each col
        List<DropInfo> allDropInfo = eData.getExplosionInfo();
        int col = allDropInfo.get(i).getCoords().getCol();
        int row = allDropInfo.get(i).getCoords().getRow();
        // If a bonusStone will apear, the heightOffset gets reduced by one
        int offset = getAppropiateOffset(bonusTargetCoords, allDropInfo.get(i), col);

        for (int r = row; r >= 0; --r) {
            // Drop all Stones above the removed Structure to fill up the empty space
            // Ignore possible bonusStones since they are being animated seperately
            if (ignoreBonusTargetCoordinates(bonusTargetCoords, bonusSourceCoords, r, col)) {
                ImageView iv = (ImageView) JavaFXGUI.getNodeFromGridPane(boardGPane, col, r);
                TranslateTransition tt = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(1500), iv);
                tt.fromYProperty().set(-rowHeight * offset);
                tt.toYProperty().set(0);
                animateDrop.getChildren().add(tt);
            }
        }

    }
    explosionAnimation.getChildren().add(animateDrop);
    return explosionAnimation;
}

private int getAppropiateOffset(Coords bonusTargetCoords, DropInfo dropInfo, int col) {
    int bonusOffset = (bonusTargetCoords != null && col == bonusTargetCoords.getCol()) ? 1 : 0;
    return dropInfo.getHeightOffset() - bonusOffset;
}

private boolean ignoreBonusTargetCoordinates(Coords bonusTargetCoords,
                                             Coords bonusSourceCoords,
                                             int row,
                                             int col) {
    return bonusSourceCoords == null
            || bonusTargetCoords != null && col != bonusTargetCoords.getCol()
            || bonusTargetCoords != null && row != bonusTargetCoords.getRow();
}
```

Comment: You have a lot of loops in your code. For clarification, is the one you mention in the question title inside the `setOnFinished` handler of `switchAnimation`? And you want the `SequentialTransition` created in the loop to run only after the one created in the previous iteration finishes, correct?

Comment: @Slaw yes exactly. - explosionAnimation

Answer (score 0):

A [`SequentialTransition`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/animation/SequentialTransition.html) can be made up of other `SequentialTransition`s. For your code you could create a "master" `SequentialTransition` and build it up with each `SequentialTransition` you create per iteration of the `for` loop. Then you would play the master transition.

```
switchAnimation.setOnFinished(event -> {
    SequentialTransition masterAnimation = new SequentialTransition();

    for (ExplosionData eData : aData.geteData()) {
        SequentialTransition explosionAnimation = new SequentialTransition();

        // ... configure the explosionAnimation ...

        masterAnimation.getChildren().add(explosionAnimation); // add to masterAnimation
    }

    masterAnimation.play(); // play all the explosionAnimations in squential order
});
```

The reason your code doesn't wait for the animation to finish before moving on to the next iteration of the loop is because [`Animation.play()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/animation/Animation.html#play()) is an "asynchronous call". 
When you call `play()` the animation gets scheduled in the background with some internal clock/timer and the method returns immediately.

> Plays `Animation` from current position in the direction indicated by
>   `rate`. If the `Animation` is running, it has no effect.
>
> When `rate > 0` (forward play), if an `Animation` is already positioned at
>   the end, the first cycle will not be played, it is considered to have
>   already finished. This also applies to a backward (`rate < 0`) cycle if
>   an `Animation` is positioned at the beginning. However, if the Animation
>   has `cycleCount > 1`, following cycle(s) will be played as usual.
>
> When the `Animation` reaches the end, the Animation is stopped and the
>   play head remains at the end.
>
> To play an `Animation` backwards from the end:
>   `animation.setRate(negative rate);`
>   `animation.jumpTo(overall duration of animation);`
>   `animation.play();`
>
> Note:
>
> **`play()` is an asynchronous call, the `Animation` may not start immediately.**

(**empasis** mine)

---

Here's a workable example. It takes a `Rectangle` and translates it to each corner of the scene. Each "translate-to-corner" is a separate animation which also involves rotating the `Rectangle` and changes its color. Then all "translate-to-corner" animations are put into one `SequentialTransition`. The `Button` at the top is disabled when clicked and re-enabled when the master `SequentialTransition` finishes.

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.ParallelTransition;
import javafx.animation.RotateTransition;
import javafx.animation.SequentialTransition;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Separator;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Main extends Application {

    private Button playBtn;
    private StackPane groupParent;
    private Rectangle rectangle;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        playBtn = new Button("Play Animation");
        playBtn.setOnAction(ae -> {
            ae.consume();
            playBtn.setDisable(true);
            playAnimation();
        });

        HBox btnBox = new HBox(playBtn);
        btnBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        btnBox.setPadding(new Insets(8));

        rectangle = new Rectangle(150, 100, Color.BLUE);
        groupParent = new StackPane(new Group(rectangle));
        groupParent.getChildren().get(0).setManaged(false);

        VBox root = new VBox(btnBox, new Separator(), groupParent);
        root.setMaxSize(600, 400);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        VBox.setVgrow(groupParent, Priority.ALWAYS);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Animation");
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void playAnimation() {
        double maxX = groupParent.getWidth() - rectangle.getWidth();
        double maxY = groupParent.getHeight() - rectangle.getHeight();

        ParallelTransition pt1 = createAnimation(-25, maxY - 25, 90, Color.FIREBRICK);
        ParallelTransition pt2 = createAnimation(maxX, maxY, 180, Color.BLUE);
        ParallelTransition pt3 = createAnimation(maxX + 25, 25, 270, Color.FIREBRICK);
        ParallelTransition pt4 = createAnimation(0, 0, 360, Color.BLUE);

        SequentialTransition st = new SequentialTransition(rectangle, pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4);
        st.setOnFinished(ae -> {
            ae.consume();
            rectangle.setTranslateX(0);
            rectangle.setTranslateY(0);
            rectangle.setRotate(0);
            playBtn.setDisable(false);
        });
        st.play();
    }

    private ParallelTransition createAnimation(double x, double y, double r, Color c) {
        TranslateTransition tt = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(1.0));
        tt.setToX(x);
        tt.setToY(y);

        RotateTransition rt = new RotateTransition(Duration.seconds(1));
        rt.setToAngle(r);

        Timeline tl = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), new KeyValue(rectangle.fillProperty(), c)));

        return new ParallelTransition(tt, rt, tl);
    }

}
```

Comment: MasterSequential Transition i tried as well,  but like you pointed out with the play issue, it didnt change the outcome. Do you have a suggestion on how to fix the play issue?

Comment: @OnFirE1337 Did you remove your `explosionAnimation.play()` call? The code posted _will_ only play each animation after the previous has completed. If you want to do something _after_ `masterAnimation` has completed you must use the `setOnFinished` callback.

Comment: yes it was exactly like your example. Still doesnt fully wait for the animation to end before iterating to the next animation.

Comment: @OnFirE1337 I added a workable example to my answer. Let me know if it represents the kind of thing you want to do. If not, then I'll probably delete this answer (since that would mean I misunderstood your question). It it is, then you most likely have issues with some other parts of your animation code.

Comment: @OnFirE1337 Something occurred to me: do you want to _stop_  `updateGui` from _returning_ until `masterAnimation` finishes?